Active pickup Guitar Wiring
So I have a guitar with EMG active pickups powered by a 9 V battery. I've been using two 23ae batteries outputting 24 V with it, but I want the ability to switch between 9 V and 24 V without taking taking out and swapping the batteries. I want to know if it's possible to hook up two batteries 9 V and 24 V to a 6-pin 110/220 V switch and use that to switch between 9 V and 24 V.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

yes, it's possible



simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Figure 1. Using one pole of a 2-pole switch for battery selection.
The schematic assumes that the switch is 2PDT (2-pole, double throw). You would only need one pole. It also assumes that the preamp power is switched by insertion of the guitar jack plug.
A switch rated for (relatively) high-current mains may not work well on the mV signals of a guitar signal. Any oxidation and contact resistance may cause signal degradation.
Also, 24 V seems a high voltage for a guitar pickup designed to run at 9 V. I would check the specification but would expect it to have destroyed the preamplifier by now if there was a problem.

Thank you! Yeah 24v is high, but peope actually do thgs mod, been running my pickup with this mod for a year with no issues whatsoever
